# vuejs instance - can I have <template> markup outside the <script>tag?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the following code in my  .vue file:

```
<template>
   <p>hello search</p>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#js-quick-search'
})
</script>
```

and in my .html I have a the element for Vue instance

```
<div id="js-quick-search"></div>
```

However, the template part is completely ignored. How can I attach it to the instance without adding it inside the script tag?

Basically I want to achieve the same as this:

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#js-quick-search',
  template: '<p>whatever</p>'
})
</script>
```

but without hard-coding template inside the script.

Comment: You don't use both `el` and `template`. If you want that template to be the contents, it should be the template of a component, which would have to be used in your original `el`. Or don't use `el`. Still not clear on what your desired result is.

Comment: Hi Roy, just trying to control a part of the html without the hassle of making components. I thought I can get away with dedicated vue instance. And it works if I have the html hard-coded in the vue constructor as a property called template. But it would be nicer to have the markup outside javascript, like you can have it in vue components. Anyway I just started with vuejs, so my approach could be totally wrong, do you have some reference where it says el and and template should not be used toghether?

Answer (score 0):

Your markup inside the `script` tag is wrong. To create a template, you'd have to export the `script`, like so:

```
<template>
  <div class="MyTemplate">
    Your template
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "MyTemplate"
}
</script>
```

To then use the template, just import it (`import MyTemplate from './MyTemplate.vue'`) and add it to your components (`components: { MyTemplate }`) then place it in as `<myTemplate>`)

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear enough - I added more info.